# Raycast2D и его позиция

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Нужно создать луч в 2Д, летящий из камеры в позицию мыши. Где и как использовать input.mouseposition?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void Update()
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); //Получение позиции мыши и перевод его в мировые коордионаты

    RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.transform.position, mousePosition); //Собственно сам луч испускаемый из центра камеры,                                                                                       дает информацию об объекте, в который попал

    if (hit.transform != null) // Проверит наличие объекта(объект должен содержать Collider) и для теста выведет сообщение
    {
        Debug.Log("Detected");
    }

}
private void OnDrawGizmos() // Это создаст тестовый луч, в окне редактирования. Можно не писать
{
    Vector2 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    Gizmos.DrawRay(Camera.main.transform.position, mousePosition);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin здесь же вроде есть комменты в коде, вдруг вы их не заметили.

Comment: @aepot, заметил. но, по-моему, эти комментарии никак не способтствуют пониманию, «Где и как использовать input.mouseposition»

Comment: input.mouseosition это свойство, которое показывает положение мыши относительно экрана, и если использовать его напрямую, то мы будем получать координаты со всего монитора, здесь же мы используем метод ScreenToWorldPoint, который переводит эти координаты в координаты мирового пространства. То есть теперь за границы камеры нельзя выйти, и мышь работает только в её области и дает верные направления векторов.

Comment: Небольшая проблема - когда я в окне Game навожу мышку на объект, луч в инспекторе светит выше, чем нужно. Можно ли это как-то решить?

Comment: Первое что приходит на ум, это добавить вектор смещения, вывести его в инспектор и прибавить данный вектор к выражению локальной переменой mousePosition. А потом уже через инспектор подобрать нужное значение. Если не понятно будет ответ с кодом могу написать ещё один

Comment: Далеко не лучшей практикой является использование `camera.main` в каждом кадре ДВАЖДЫ! [Camera.main](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera-main.html?_ga=2.224073563.135382510.1631371657-1923852737.1614090816): `Accessing this property has a small CPU overhead, comparable to calling GameObject.GetComponent. Where CPU performance is important, consider caching this property.` (а учитывая OnDrawGizmos - четырежды)

Comment: Спасибо за замечание с camera.main. Думаю это можно исправить, просто переместив компонент на камеру, и заменить первый параметр Raycast на transform.position. А об использовании в OnDrawGizmos, так как данный метод используется на стадии создания прототипа и разработки, не думаю что стоит так сильно беспокоится о производительности на данном этапе.

Comment: Хотя лучшем решением для оптимизации, будет кеширование компонентов, но думаю в данном небольшом скрипте это излишнее